# ResolveAssemblyReference slowness -- msbuild speed?

Tags: c#, msbuild, incremental-build

I have a project with maybe 200+ projects in it. It's an old bird. To make local builds faster, I ran a diagnostic build. Seems resolving assembly and project references is taking msbuild awhile. VS seems to do this fast, is there a way to get MSBuild to use a cache for these references, or to somehow resolve it faster?

It seems MSBuild wouldn't need to resolve the assembly reference(s) this often with an incremental build, right?

Is there a way to get MSBuild to report its internal dependency tree for this?

Comment: This is caused by your hard disk, it takes a while to locate the files when the file system cache is cold.  Between 8 and 20 seconds for a solution that size, give or take.  It *looks* fast from VS because VS is doing it the background, while you are doing something else.  An SSD is nice.

Answer (score 0):

VS uses the same MSBuild engine to perform the build, so whatever performance you observe from VS, you should be able to achieve by starting build from command line using MSBuild.exe.

There are couple of points to keep in mind, that might explain difference in build speed between VS and command line:

1. If you build "Project Only" in VS, i.e. right click on the project node, select "Build Project (this)" from "Project Only" menu, then the build skips building any referenced projects. This is the fastest way to do incremental build, but you have to know ahead of time that all dependencies are up-to-date.

If you want to replicate this from command line, just pass parameter BuildProjectReferences=false. E.g:

```
msbuild myproject.csproj /p:BuildProjectReferences=false
```

2. The defaults for VS might be set for multi-proc build, which in many cases greatly increases build speed. However on command line, the defaults are always to perform single-proc build, so that would appear much slower than VS. Always pass in /m to the msbuild command line. E.g.:

```
msbuild MySolution.sln /m
```